# gdb.execute('ptype..) command does not display enum type for an array whose type is enum

Tags: python

In my python script, when I write gdb.execute('ptype..) command it does not output the enum type for an array whose type is enum. Instead it outputs all the enum members but does not output the name of the enum type. Any ideas how to get the enum type name?

types_names = gdb.execute('ptype %s' % stripped_type.tag, to_string=True)

I wrote:
types_names = gdb.execute('ptype %s' % stripped_type.tag, to_string=True)

I get:

(Pdb) p types_names
'type = struct Vd3d::BoxConfidenceData {\n    enum : unsigned int {Vd3d::SC_NOT_INITIALIZED,   Vd3d::SC_BAD_STICK, Vd3d::SC_PROBABLY_BAD_STICK, Vd3d::SC_PROBABLY_GOOD_STICK, Vd3d::SC_GOOD_STICK, Vd3d::NUM_SC} stickConf[4];\n

Instead of getting:
type = struct Vd3d::BoxConfidenceData {\n   Vd3d::STICK_CONFIDENCE stickConf[4];

Comment: Is that a C++ type?  Is it an enum class?

Comment: yes it is a c++ class where we have a structure that contains an array of type enum  
 - Vd3d::BoxConfidenceData stickConf[4]

Comment: This question would benefit from proper formatting of your code samples (there is syntax help available from the editor).

Comment: In my humble opinion, you are expecting too much.  The fact that the debugger can extract as much information as it did is pretty darned impressive.  The information might not be available in the debug symbols.

Comment: the input is a pointer to the defintion of the c++ class (*.h file). So it should have all the info